# Почему на линуксе переключение языка с помощью shift+alt срабатывает быстрее, чем на виндовсе?

Tags: linux, windows, естественный-язык

Почему на линуксе переключение языка с помощью shift+alt срабатывает быстрее, чем на виндовсе? Заметно когда быстро печатаеш и нужно русское сообщение набрать переключаешь и на винде не успевает а на линуксе ок

Comment: что-то с вашей виндой не то

Comment: @PavelGridin с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: В двух этих ОС, можно также пользоваться комбинацией клавиш: `Windows + Space`, работает с одинаковой скоростью

Comment: @L.F.C. да, но это будет ещё медленнее, так как пальцы не привыкли

Comment: У меня на windows язык переключается мгновенно. Если у вас переключается медленно, это проблема именно на вашей системе.

Comment: я на capslock переключаю. так ещё проще (правда в линуксе. винды у меня нет и по слухам в ней так нельзя).

Comment: может FilterKeys включен? попробуйте подержать Shift восемь секунд

Comment: Винду проверьте на вирусы а еще лучше переставьте винду. Версия-то какая винды?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что это совершенно разные операционные системы. Причём, Линукс - это ядро, а не ОС. Тут разница в скорости переключения раскладки будет даже не только между дистрибутивами, но и между графическими окружениями на одном дистрибутиве GNU/Linux.

Comment: А можно как-нибудь ускорить переключение на винде?

Comment: не знаю даже, не изучал подобных оптимизаций.

Answer (score 6):

Вероятно, так происходит потому, что в windows переключение раскладок срабатывает по событию *отпускания* клавиш, а в GNU/Linux/X11 — по *нажатию*.

На самом деле это не столько преимущество, сколько [старый](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865) [баг](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/258) X11 (xkb) из-за которого невозможно использовать горячие клавиши <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Что-то там</kbd> или <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Что-то там</kbd>, когда настроена переключение по соответствующей комбинации.

Comment: ЗЫ: ИМХО очень удачный выбор для переключения раскладки — `Caps Lock`. Удобное расположен под мизинцем, а раскладку переключать приходиться куда чаще, чем печатать капсом.

Comment: У меня в Windows 8/10 иногда бывало, что после переключения раскладки и отпускания всех клавиш текст набирался на предыдущей раскладке ещё секунд пять

Comment: нуда... я тут подумал — скорей всего это не связано... при быстрой печати, если не успеть отпустить, то win должен был бы обработать последовательность нажатий как хоткей, а не печать на старой раскладке...